# how to read csv file's create and update metadata in cloud function and add it as columns to the csv

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, metadata

I receive daily CSV files from Google Compute Engine into my Storage bucket and I wrote a Cloud Function that loads these CSV's data into a BigQuery table and it goes well.
However, I need to include file creation time and file update time from the CSV file metadata as columns before sending the data to BigQuery table or as it is being sent.

Is this possible in Cloud Function and how can I do that?
I would appreciate it if there is some kind of example that you can guide me to.

```py
# my code in cloud functions
import os

from google.cloud import bigquery

GCP_PROJECT = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT')


def FlexToBigQuery(data, context):
    bucketname = data['bucket']
    filename = data['name']
    timeCreated = data['timeCreated']

    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_id = 'My-dataset'
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()

    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job_config.field_delimiter = ';',
    job_config.allow_jagged_rows = True
    job_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV

    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('Anstallningsnummer', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Datum', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Kod', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Kostnadsstalle', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Tidkod', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('OB_tidkod', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Dagsschema', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Schemalagd_arbetstid', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Summa_narvaro', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Summa_franvaro', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Datum_for_klarmarkering', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Datum_for_attestering', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Frislappsdatum', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Export_klockslag', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Vecka', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE')
    ]

    uri = 'gs://%s/%s' % (bucketname, filename)
    print('Received file "%s" at %s.' % (
        uri,
        timeCreated
    ))

    # get the URI for uploaded CSV in GCS from 'data'
    uri = 'gs://' + data['bucket'] + '/' + data['name']

    # lets do this
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        dataset_ref.table('employee_time'),
        job_config=job_config)

    print('Starting job with ID {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    print('File: {}'.format(data['name']))

    load_job.result()  # wait for table load to complete.
    print('Job finished.')

    destination_table = client.get_table(dataset_ref.table('employee_time'))
    print('Loaded {} rows.'.format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists these two functions [`os.path.getmtime`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) and [`os.path.getctime`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) to get the creation and update time from the a file that you can use before sending the data to BigQuery.

```
import os.path, time

print("updated: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
print("created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))
```

May be similar to [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python/237084#237084)